# How to set postion to the tick if you use scaleLinear

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

[Using d3 in react having 0 in domain, it centers "zero" tick.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKiCN.png)

[While useing in HTML  there's no such "problem", how to reach the same result in react?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Kvo.png)

Code example:

```
var width = 400, height = 400;
var data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
     // if value is 0, the tick is centered, if there is a range, it draws the ticks first tick is on the needed position
        .domain([0, value])
        .range([height/2, 0]);

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yscale);

    svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
       .call(y_axis);
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please elaborate your issue. Its difficult to understand problem with just images. I would recommend to always attach a working demo so that others can follow you easily.

Comment: @Jasdeep Singh edit the question, hope, now it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the desired behavior and i would say that the d3 is working perfectly.

if data in value is 0, the we are mapping [0,0] for entire y axis and d3 rendering it in middle of axis.

```js
var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
     // if value is 0, the tick is centered, if there is a range, it draws the ticks first tick is on the needed position
        .domain([0, value])
        .range([height/2, 0]);
```

In order to fix this issue, we need to make our code more logical. We can check for maximum entry for "value" and respond according. Just set a minimum value if the value is less than that value.For eg: i am using 5. In this way your chart would look a lot better.

Please use below code and let me know if it resolves your issue.

```js
value = value <= 5 ? 5: value;

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  // if value is 0, the tick is centered, if there is a range, it draws the ticks first tick is on the needed position
  .domain([0, value])
  .range([height / 2, 0]);
```

Comment: Having 0 in value ( domain([0,0]),I need to draw this tick at the bottom of the scale, like it works in html. 
And your decision is just to set any number except 0.

Comment: Yes, we set domain for a chart so that user can see all the values (from minimum to maximum) within a small space. There is no point of setting [0,0] in domain. We can set the second parameter of domain to a small value like i am setting 5. So that we can see all smaller values and chart axis can render perfectly.

Comment: Singth
thanks for help, in generlal it's quite good problem solution, but in fact the customer wants exaclty without minimum ticks

Comment: Can you please create a working instance or jsfiddle of your issue.